# Instantiate a map with default

Tags: scala

So, I have a list of characters and I have to create a list which says how many there are of each kind

```
( List(a,a,a,a,b,b)   => List ( (a,4), (b,3))
```

I wanted to create a map that would list each character to 1 at first

```
( (a->1), (a->1), (a->1), (a->1), (b->1), (b->1))
```

and then use group by + tolist to return the final list. The problem is creating a map requires a PHD in this language.

I tried

```
val m = xs.foldLeft(Map[Char,Int]()){c => c->1}
```

Which doesn't work.

```
xs map (x=> x-> 1) toMap
```

Which compiles but I can't do anything with this map afterwards.

and `xs.toMap(x,1)`
Which doesn't work either.

Could somebody tell me how I should proceed please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` to do the grouping and then find the count of each group:

```
list.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
```

Comment: You can just use `l.groupBy(identity)` (instead of `l.groupBy(identity _)` ).